# React Native + MongoDB Stitch: this.client.getServiceClient is not a function

Tags: mongodb, react-native, mongodb-stitch

I am trying to create a simple connection to my MongoDB database collection for my Stitch App. In the `componentDidMount()` method I initialize the default app client and store it in a variable of the component. But when I try to set the MongoDB remote after, it doesn't work, I get the

**`TypeError: this.client.getServiceClient is not a function. (In 'this.client.getServiceClient(MongoDB.RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb-atlas")', 'this.client.getServiceClient' is undefined)`**

[image: screenshot of Expo error screen]

I have read all React Native docs such as [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch-sdks/js-react-native/4/index.html) or [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-ios-and-android-apps-with-the-mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk) and see the structure isn't the same but I don't want the user to log in on the app (why I used the `AnonymousCredential()`) and even if I were to use this structure, I wouldn't know what to do once the user is logged in, how to get the data? Since there is no Remote Client defined, therefore no db and no collection.

Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, FlatList } from "react-native";
import PlayerItem from "./PlayerItem";
import { Stitch, AnonymousCredential } from "mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk";
const MongoDB = require("mongodb-stitch-react-native-services-mongodb-remote");

export default class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            players: [],
        };
        this.query = "";
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.client = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("kungfuzone-rzksu");
        const mongodb = this.client.getServiceClient(
            MongoDB.RemoteMongoClient.factory,
            "mongodb-atlas"
        );

        this.db = mongodb.db("players");
        this._displayPlayersOnLoad();
    }

    _displayPlayersOnLoad() {
        this.client.auth
            .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
            .then(this._displayPlayers)
            .catch(console.error);
    }

    _displayPlayers() {
        this.db
            .collection("kungfuzone")
            .find({}, { limit: 1000 })
            .asArray()
            .then((players) => {
                this.setState({ players: players });
            });
    }

    _updateQuery(text) {
        this.query = text;
    }

    _searchPlayers(query) {
        if (query.length > 0) {
            this.stitchClient.auth
                .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
                .then(() => this.setState({ players: db.find({ name: query }).asArray() }))
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textinput}
                    onChangeText={(input) => this._updateQuery(input)}
                    placeholder="Player's name"
                />
                <Button title="Search" onPress={() => this._searchPlayers(this.query)} />
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.players}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <PlayerItem player={item} />}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    textinput: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        height: 50,
        borderColor: "#000000",
        borderWidth: 1,
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
});
```

Can anyone help? Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's not a good idea to make a connection directly to a remote database from your mobile application. How about to use the [atlas API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/) or create an API to communicate with MongoDB?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would I need a server for that? Or can I fetch that from React directly? I would still need to connect/authenticate to the database though, right?

Comment: @Maëlle, you're using Stitch as it is intended. It is specifically built for "serverless" architecture.